# JavaScript window.open function is displaying toolbar and menubar when instructed not to in IE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-7

I am currently trying to open another IE window using the code below, but the toolbar and menubar is still showing under IE7, it seems to work under IE8 though. Why is it doing this?

```
mywindow = window.open("dataviewer.aspx?id=" + id , "", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no");
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall having to add a website to my "trusted sites" list in IE7 to get the toolbars hidden.  Of course that isn't going to help if you can't control that for your visitors, but I think it was something locked down as of IE7 -- even though MSDN doesn't state that.  It might be an advanced setting, or maybe it was related to some 3rd party add-on or anti-virus I had.  I just know I had a website that launched a small window that was meant to be a "floating toolbar" and it worked great in IE6, but once I upgraded to IE7 the width and height worked, but it had toolbars.  I added that site to my trusted sites list, and it started working again.

If that is the case for you, I'd check the advanced security features and see what is different between normal and trusted sites, and maybe fine the one setting that controls this.

Comment: I tried adding it to the trusted site list, disabling all add-ons, and lowering all security settings to the lowest level; it didn't help for my case.

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE7-mode in IE9.  I don't have a machine with *real* IE7 installed.

The `directories` features is no longer supported.  Just a guess, but that might be your problem.

One thing to try is to specify *only* `"toolbar=no"`.  Once you've specified to disable one of the features, the rest of them default to `no`.  If you wanted no toolbars, but you did want an address bar, you'd have to explicitly say `"location=yes"` to get them back on.  So, setting just one feature to `no` is good enough to turn the rest of them off as well.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VD8sk/

```
mywindow = open("dataviewer.aspx?id=" + id , "", "toolbar=no");
```

**Edit:** Maybe also try `"toolbar=no,menubar=no"` without the other features specified.

Comment: It works in IE7-mode in IE8 for me as well, just not the normal IE7 when I try it. I originally did it without the directories feature and it still was not working. I'll give your other suggestion a go.

Comment: Tried just setting `toolbar=no` and it did not work. I am using IE 7.0.5730.13.